# Server Side Fingerprint Comparison with Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, access-control, fingerprint, biometrics

I have 3 doors that need controlled access for customers (over 1000).

Currently I use RFID cards. I have 3 raspberry pies + rfid scanners installed in all 3 doors and they call my API with the rfid value and open the door upon authentication.

I want to switch to Fingerprint authentication instead of RFID. But all the fingerprint scanner I’ve come across do the storing and comparison process on device. This doesn’t work for me as I have 3 doors(I need to register the fingerprint from one device and work on all) and over 1000 fingerprints.

My idea is to scan the fingerprint using a scanner and upload the image output to server through API  for registration and comparison.

Are there any fingerprint scanner devices that support image output? And any php library to compare fingerprint by image(as my existing API is php based)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own Automatic Finger Identification algorithm and expose as an web service, or you have to use third party services such as

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)